# How to check a value contain in multi dimensional string array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

how to check a value contain in multi dimensional string array in java 8 .

So far i have been using this,

```
public  boolean exists(String value) {

    String[][] actType=Helper.getTypes();
    for(int i = 0; i< actType.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<actType[i].length; j++){
            if(actType[i][j].equals(value)){
                return true; 
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I  want to know, is there any java 8 methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested `Stream.of(T values...)` to turn your array to a stream and then use method references:

```
public  boolean exists(String value) {
    String[][] actType=Helper.getTypes();
    return Stream.of(actType).flatMap(Stream::of).anyMatch(value::equals);
}
```

`Stream.of(actType)` will get you a stream of `String[]` and `flatMap` in combination with another `Stream::of` will get you a stream of `String`. If any of those strings equal your value `anyMatch` will return `true`.